# reverse proxy doesn't work with .svc url?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

here's my attempt to do a reverse proxy using url rewrite in `IIS` from `mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com` to `mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com`

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="400-999" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://mysubdomainreal.myrealdomain.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I call website using `mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com/myApp` it works (render the page/etc). But if I call `mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com/myApp.svc` I got an 404.

Why? Where am I wrong on this configuration?

**EDIT**
Here's the failedRequest tag's attribute:

```
<failedRequest url="http://mysubdomaintarget.mytargetdomain.com/myApp.svc"
               siteId="6"
               appPoolId="services"
               processId="2192"
               verb="GET"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{8000002B-0000-9900-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="404"
               triggerStatusCode="404"
               timeTaken="141"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
```

**EDIT2**

Here's the last event I got from failed request tracking:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-11T09:26:41.979Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000549-1000-FB00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="2192" ThreadID="2264"/>
  <Computer>MyPC</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000549-1000-FB00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesSent">2180</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesReceived">993</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">404</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_END</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

its not "talking" at all. Where do I see any error from this last Event?

**EDIT3**

xml opened by browser:

[image]

Comment: Can you post detailed error information about 404? or you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: @samwu enabled, and edited the answer! That's the first tag I got, but its not so "speaking". Which tag do I need to investigate more?

Comment: EDIT: added the whole web.config, so we can investigate further!

Comment: When you use failed request tracking, you will get an xml file, after opening it, you will see a detailed error message.

Comment: @samwu i don't see any "detailed" error that express to me what's going wrong :O

Comment: @samwu added last Event. as you can see, can't get the error from it...

Comment: refer to this link about how to Troubleshoot Application Request Routing: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).

Comment: @samwu added xml view in browser. what does it means?

Comment: There's something wrong in your web.config, a path to a request handler is not right. Verify all of the path information is correct in the <httpHandlers> section of your web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow WCF to use multiple domain you should set `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled` to `true`.
The following configuration should fix your issue.

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

`multipleSiteBindingsEnabled`

> A Boolean value that specifies whether multiple IIS bindings per site is enabled. 
> IIS consists of web sites, which are containers for virtual applications containing virtual directories. The application in a site can be accessed through one or more IIS binding. An IIS binding provides two pieces of information: a binding protocol and binding information. Binding protocol defines the scheme over which communication occurs, and binding information is the information used to access the site. An example of a binding protocol can be HTTP, whereas binding information can contain an IP address, Port, host header, etc.
> IIS supports specifying multiple IIS bindings per site, which results in multiple base addresses per scheme. However, a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service hosted under a site allows binding to only one baseAddress per scheme.
> To enable multiple IIS bindings per site for a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service, set this attribute to true. Notice that multiple site binding is supported only for the HTTP protocol. The address of endpoints in the configuration file needs to be a complete URI.

Comment: but i'm not calling the wcf directly, but from a url rewrite on another server... isn't this for different bindings on the same server?

Comment: I had a similar issue and that's what fixed it. I'm not sure why/how WCF works with multiple pseudo binding. Where did you put the config ? you should put it in the target website not in the reverse proxy config.

Comment: Yes, I've put it in the app website

Comment: Now the app says "The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'."

Comment: `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` may not be required in your case. You can just ignore it or set it to `false` (default value)